# 2d Billiard power physics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have what I think is a mathematical problem with my power engine and I've spent the past 2 days trying to solve this.  I am relatively new to programming and am in the process of developing a 2D top-down billiard game in Unity.

My code is attached below, but essentially the player will click on the ball and drag back to produce power.  Once they reach the desired power and let go the ball will launch in the desired direction at the desired power.  For the sake of this example let's say that I set maxPower to 100, and the player object's linear drag and the tile drag remains constant.  In the following example scenarios, all shots are at full power, and I'm shooting from the bottom left of my table:

1. I shoot a purely x-axis shot - the ball is shot at 100 power to the right
2. I shoot a purely y-axis shot - the ball is shot at 100 power upwards
3. I shoot at a 45 degree angle - how can I calculate what happens here?

If you look at the code below, I am using AddForce to push the ball on the x and y axis once I release the mouse.  I'm tracking the distance of each shot made at a variety of angles and I've tried the following power management:

1. Splitting the power between x and y axis - this ends up produces a much weaker shot than a pure x/y axis shot (50 power per axis)
2. Giving each axis the full power - this ends up producing a much more powerful shot (100 power per axis)
3. Feeling like Goldilocks, I tried to make this juuuuust right and compute this using the Pythagorean theorem, and this is where I am struggling.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Code below - all variables are defined, I've just removed irrelevant code.

```
    public float maxForce = 100;
    public float forceMultiplier = 2


    void Awake() {

        startPosition = transform.position;

    }

    void Update () {     

        /// Tracks distance (start vs current)
        distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,startPosition);

        //On Click
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {   

            startPosX = Input.mousePosition.x;
            startPosY = Input.mousePosition.y;
        }

        /// While being clicked
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {

            ///  Determines force to be applied based on mouse drag
            current_xForce = (startPosX - Input.mousePosition.x);
            current_yForce = (startPosY - Input.mousePosition.y);

            // Stores the original drag angle
            yCheck = current_yForce;
            xCheck = current_xForce;


            ///  if current x/y force is greater than maxForce, set to maxForce
            if (current_yForce > 0 && current_yForce > maxForce)
                current_yForce = maxForce;
            if (current_yForce < 0 && current_yForce < -maxForce)
                current_yForce = -maxForce;
            if (current_xForce > 0 && current_xForce > maxForce)
                current_xForce = maxForce;
            if (current_xForce < 0 && current_xForce < -maxForce)
                current_xForce = -maxForce;

            //  Determines the % of x/y while aiming
            current_xPercentage = Mathf.Abs (current_xForce) / (Mathf.Abs (current_xForce) + Mathf.Abs (current_yForce));
            current_yPercentage = Mathf.Abs (current_yForce) / (Mathf.Abs (current_xForce) + Mathf.Abs (current_yForce));

            //  Decides the Power bar% - power determined by highest powered axis (may need improvement)
            current_powerPercent = Mathf.Max (Mathf.Abs (current_xForce)/maxForce, Mathf.Abs (current_yForce)/maxForce);


            //  get angle from start position to relative mouse position... add relative mouse position   NOT WORKING... need degrees
            shotAngle = Vector2.Angle(startPosition,Input.mousePosition);
        }

        // Mouse button released
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {               

            ///  Only shots with greater than % of total power count - allows you to cancel shots
            if (current_powerPercent >= 0.10) {

                ///  Increase force by public multiplier
                xForce = current_xForce * forceMultiplier ;    
                yForce = current_yForce * forceMultiplier ;



                ///  Use % of absolute xCheck to determine shot angle 
                float xForcePercent = Mathf.Abs (xCheck) / (Mathf.Abs (yCheck) + Mathf.Abs (xCheck));
                float yForcePercent = Mathf.Abs (yCheck) / (Mathf.Abs (yCheck) + Mathf.Abs (xCheck));

                ///  Adds force to x/y based off xForce and the shot angle
                float x_addForce = xForce * xForcePercent;
                float y_addForce = yForce * yForcePercent;

                ///  Attempt at a-squared + b-squared = c-squared.... this is supposed to return c
                powerVar = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow (x_addForce*xForcePercent, 2) + Mathf.Pow (y_addForce*yForcePercent, 2));


                ///  Applies the force to the player object.. .for each axis I take powerVar * angle * sign (to adjust for negative values)
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(powerVar*xForcePercent*Mathf.Sign(x_addForce), powerVar*yForcePercent*Mathf.Sign(y_addForce)));


                yForce = 0;
                xForce = 0;
                startPosX = 0;
                startPosY = 0;   
                distance = 0;
                startPosition = transform.position;  /// resets Distance counter


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what's the problem? Why don't you just use the [x, y] diff of mouse-down start and mouse-down end for the calculation? So if I moved the mouse from [0, 0] to have 100% power under 45° angle (which is not your actual input, right? It's the mouse positions...) I'd be at [70.7, 70.7] as per basic trigonometry and/or circle equation and therefore 70.7% of max power in either dimension.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - my yCheck and xCheck track the [x,y] difference of the mouse.
You're correct that if I drag the mouse at a 45 degree angle enough I'd be at 100% power - I'm struggling with writing a formula that will find the 70.7%  of maxForceand apply it the AddForce.  I imagine the same formula would apply to a non-symmetrical angle as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) dictates that in a right triangle the following is true:

```
c * c = a * a + b * b
```

Where `c` is the hypotenuse. Now, in your case `c` is `100` and the angle between `c` and `a` or `b` is `45°`. This means you are equally "splitting" `c` between `a` and `b`. Ok, let's do that:

```
a = b, therefore:
c * c = a * a + a * a, which means
c * c = 2 * a * a
```

If we take the square root on both sides:

```
c = sqrt(2) * a, and therefore
a = c / sqrt(2)
```

You will see this same relation written may times in the following form:

```
a = sqrt(2)/2 * c
```

And there you go. In your case if `c` is `100` then `a` and `b` will be `70,711`.

You can generalize this for any angle if you use [trigonometric functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) (based on the Pythagorean theorem). For any angle `d` between `c` and `a`, the following is true:

```
 a = c * cos(d)
 b = c * sin(d)
```

Make sure you get your units right if you are going to use trigonometric functions. Angles are normally given in *radians*, not degrees, the relation between the two is:

```
 180 degrees = pi radians
```

Comment: Thanks so much InBetween!  You gave me the logic I needed and after some trial and error (and re-learning 8th grade math..) I managed to get it working perfectly